# Pandas Group by and sum by times before time listed in row

Tags: python, pandas

Fun problem!

I have a data frame that has many columns, but the relevant ones are: id, event_time

The ids are repeatable. I am trying to count all the times an id occurs in the data frame before the time of the id in each row. So if id = 43 and event_time = 2016-01-01 12:00:00 , I want the count of all the times id 43 occurs before this event_time. The event_time has already been formatted with pd.to_datetime() but it is not the index.

This loop solves the problem, but it is horrifically slow for 400k + rows.

```
occs=[]
for ix in range(len(df)):
    cur=df.iloc[[ix]]
    occurrences=df[(df.id==cur.id.values[0])&
    (df.event_time < cur.event_time.values[0])]
    occs.append(len(occurrences))
df['total_occ']=occs
```

I *know* there has to be a better way, probably using group by. The key is that it has to be ONLY times before the event_time and they are NOT in order.

Thanks everyone!

*** EDIT SAMPLE DATA ***

```
 id      |        event_time        |      count
 11               2016-11-09                1
 8                2016-11-10                1
 32               2016-11-08                0
 11               2016-11-08                0
 8                2016-11-11                2
 8                2016-11-07                0
```

(the counts will be much higher though, in the thousands... and count is the desired output)

Comment: Can you add data sample with desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be what you are after:

```
#sort df by id and datetime
df.sort_values(['id','event_time'],inplace=True)
#add cumulative count for each id.
df['count'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()

df
Out[1114]: 
   id event_time  count
5   8 2016-11-07      0
1   8 2016-11-10      1
4   8 2016-11-11      2
3  11 2016-11-08      0
0  11 2016-11-09      1
2  32 2016-11-08      0
```

Comment: That was **exactly** what I was looking for. It ran <1 second and works great. You're a hero Allen!

Comment: No worries @LoisKeller. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I'm guessing you mean to count the occurrences of `id` where `event_time` is before an `event_time` associated with the `id`, which is taken to be the event time of the first occurrence of the given `id`.

So figure out what these event times are:

```
first_event_times = df.groupby('id', as_index = False).event_time.first().rename(columns = {'first_event':'first_event_time'})
```

Merge those first event times with the dataframe, and only keep the relevant columns:

```
df0 = df[['id','event_time']].merge(first_event_times)
```

Filter down to rows where `event_time < first_event_time`:

```
df0 = df0[df0.event_time < df0.first_event_time]
```

Get the row counts for each `id` in what's left:

```
df0.groupby(['id','first_event_time']).size().to_frame('count') # gives you the desired output
```

Comment: So on the first line of code I got 

    TypeError: 'set' object is not callable

But I think the merge is the right idea